# Express $x^{x+1}=2$ in the form of $ye^y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Shown in the title above, I was trying to solve this equation using Lambert W function. But because of cannot get rid of that $1$ ,I cannot convert I the equation in the form of $ye^y$ to use the Lambert W function.

I only work until $ye^y=ln10 log 2-y$ for $y=\frac{ln 10 log 2}{x+1}$ and I am stucked.Can somebody help me please?Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this could be done.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: If it were $x^x$, it would be doable ([WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E(x)+%3D+2+for+x) agrees), but with $x+1$ in the exponent, this becomes a lot more difficult, and neither I nor [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E(x+%2B+1)+%3D+2+for+x) can solve it.

Comment: I already succeeded in $x^x$ but after trying $x^{x+1}$,I completely feel defeated

Comment: If it were solvable with the Lambert W function, substituting $x=e^{aW(b)}$ would simplify.  That's how I usually check @Arthur